# Want a Cell to position right above the footer in the last page

Tags: fpdf

I am creating a PDF document with FPDF. Everything is fine but I want a Cell right above the footer. The image can describe it best. How to do that?[image]

Comment: please show what you've done..

Answer (score 0):

[image: refer image link for clarity]

find the xy coordinates of cell you want to print(point A in the image)(trial and error..cant help) and use SetXY()...